# change html lang attribute dynamically with php

Tags: php, html, attributes, lang

I have a web with two languages.
I would like to set the attribute html lang to two languages,
this is what i would like to do, however it does not work.

```
    if($domain == 'es') {
    $language = 'es';
    } else {
    $language = 'en';
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="<?php $language ?>">
```

Comment: Would help if you actually output the $language-variable. This would be the correct syntax: `<?php echo $language; ?>` or `<?= $language; ?>`

Comment: thanks, so stupid, thought was not possible on html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

small synatx error
try this

```
<html lang="<?php echo $language; ?>">
```

else use

```
<html lang="<?= $language; ?>">
```

Comment: I did, but it says it is counted, but as i have less of 15 won't be stated, sorry, don't let me